# How to make a script run when selecting all but one link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a script run when you select a link. I have that part working, however I want it to not run when you select the main one (English). I'm sure I'm missing something basic but I have no idea what it could be. Here is what I have so far:

Script:

```
function disclaimer() {
  if ($( "a[title!='English']")) {
     alert('Disclaimer here');
  }
}
```

PHP:

```
$block_content .= '<a href="#top" 
onclick="doGTranslate(\''.$gtranslate_main_lang.'|'.$lang.'\'); 
disclaimer();jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(\'div.selected 
a\').html(jQuery(this).html());" title="'.$lang_name.'" class="nturl '.
($current_language == $lang ? ' selected' : '').'"><span class="gflag" 
style="background-position:-'.$flag_x.'px -'.$flag_y.'px;"><img 
src="'.base_path().drupal_get_path('module', 'gtranslate').'/gtranslate-
files/blank.png" height="16" width="16" alt="'.$lang_name.'" />
</span>'.$lang_name.'</a>';
```

Produced HTML:

```
<a href="#top" onclick="doGTranslate('en|en'); 
disclaimer();jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('div.selected 
a').html(jQuery(this).html());" title="English" class="nturl  selected">
<span class="gflag" style="background-position:-0px -0px;"><img 
src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/gtranslate/gtranslate-files/blank.png" 
height="16" width="16" alt="English"></span>English</a>

<a href="#top" onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr'); 
disclaimer();jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('div.selected 
a').html(jQuery(this).html());" title="French" class="nturl "><span 
class="gflag" style="background-position:-200px -100px;"><img 
src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/gtranslate/gtranslate-files/blank.png" 
height="16" width="16" alt="French"></span>French</a>

<a href="#top" onclick="doGTranslate('en|de'); 
disclaimer();jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('div.selected 
a').html(jQuery(this).html());" title="German" class="nturl "><span 
class="gflag" style="background-position:-300px -100px;"><img 
src="/sites/all/modules/contrib/gtranslate/gtranslate-files/blank.png" 
height="16" width="16" alt="German"></span>German</a>
```

As I said, I want the script to run when French or German are selected, but not English. I've tried several things but nothing seems to work. Any help or point in the right direction is greatly appreciated. If I need to post anything else that might help you, please let me know!

Comment: What are the several things you've tried?

Comment: Various things I've read on forums. If needed I can add everything to my post.

Comment: Please do explain the approaches you have tried in a concise manner so other users can help you better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example links - modifed to use `this` object identifier
Not tested but looks like it should work ~ no doubt jQuery has a far more refined way of doing it though.

```
<a href='#' onclick='disclaimer(this)' title='English'>English</a>
<a href='#' onclick='disclaimer(this)' title='French'>French</a>
<a href='#' onclick='disclaimer(this)' title='German'>German</a>


function disclaimer(n) {
    if( n.hasAttribute('title') && n.getAttribute('title')!='English' )alert('Disclaimer here');
}
```

Comment: I can try this in a little bit and let you know. Looks promising.

Comment: Would it be at all possible for you to explain why this worked using the `this` feature? I'm trying to learn as much as I can about javascript/jquery so I'd really like to know. Thanks!

Comment: As quoted on MDN - `When code is called from an in–line on-event handler, its "this" is set to the DOM element on which the listener is placed:` ~ ie: it automatically gives you a direct handle on the element in the dom. You don't assign `this` within the function or it's arguments for this type of usage but instead, as I did, have a-n-other variable that is assign `this` within the function

Comment: You could alternatively have used `event` as the argument and then, within the function, you would use `event.target` to refer to the DOM element upon which the `event` was triggered. It depends upon the scenario which approach you would use in many instances - inline functions are easy when using `this` as the argument